# Interface Builder / Putting UIButton in front of UIImageView (when UIButtons have been created before UImageView...)

Tags: interface, uiimageview, uibutton, builder

I have already defined several buttons in a view with Interface Builder. Now, I would like to add an UIImageView in this view. The idea is to have the UIImageView display behind the already existing buttons. I have dropped a new UIImage View in the view but curiously, I cannot get the image appear under the buttons (buttons are hidden by the fresh UIImageView). When I move my old buttons onto the UIImageView, then they remain in front of them but I guess there is another way to reach what I want. Is not there a concept of "foreground/background level" for each object ? I also noticed that dropping a new button works fine. But I do not want to redefine all my existing buttons are they are already connected to my code.

Thanks for your help

Apple 92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just open the Document window of the IB (Click on Window--> Document).

Once opened expand the view block and drag the UIImageView just added above the UIbuttons previously added in the list. This will do the needful

Hope this helps!!