# Background of my view hides buttons

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton

I set an image as a background for my view but when I add buttons, it doesn`t appear, the image hides the buttons. Can you help me please :)

Comment: may be post how you add your buttons and background image?

Comment: i didn`t make any code for the background, in IB i make image view and i set the background property and add an image, after that, when i build and go i can`t see my buttons, so the image hides it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a UIView which contains a UIImageView (the background image) and some UIButtons?

When you add the UIButtons in code, do the following for each button:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:aButton];
```

Comment: Hi, my UIButtons are not added in code, so i have for each button just an IBAction, should i put your line code in each IBAction ?

Comment: @Malek, No then you need to select the image view in IB, for xcode 4 select the Editor Menu->Arrangement->Send To Back, and for xcode 3 select the Layout Menu->Send To Back

Comment: THX a lot, it works, last question, how can i know the version of my xcode (xcode4 or xcode3) ? :))

Comment: Well which ever menu options you used will tell, but if you want the exact version, choose the Xcode Menu and then click About.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer Jonathan above is perfect, but as a reference you can use [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984690/interface-builder-putting-uibutton-in-front-of-uiimageview-when-uibuttons-have/4991924#4991924) as another approach to handle all the placements of the views and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually put the buttons inside the view in the view hierarchy? They might just be behind it.

Comment: the image view and all my buttons are just under the view in the view hierarchy, is it a question of opacity ??